# Define getting property on query using SailsJS model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I want to query a library by id, and I need only some properties. I tried below script but it is not working:

```
Library.findOne({
  id: libraryId
}, {
  latitude: 1, longitude: 1,
  name: 1, address: 1, image: 1
}).exec(function (err, libObj) {
  if (err)
    return res.ok(err);

  return res.ok(libObj);
});
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Not working how? Apart from the general suspicion that the "sails/waterline" query expectation is for different syntax, and most likely in the "projection" portion itself.

Comment: the data still returning all properties, although I defined 5 of it (latitude, longitude, name, address, image).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For projections you could use the **[`native()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native)** method that has direct access to the mongo driver:

```
var criteria = { id: libraryId },
    projection = { latitude: 1, longitude: 1, name: 1, address: 1, image: 1 };
// Grab an instance of the mongo-driver
Library.native(function(err, collection) {        
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);

    // Execute any query that works with the mongo js driver
    collection.findOne(criteria, projection).exec(function (err, libObj) {
        console.log(libObj);
    });
});
```

-- **UPDATE** --

Another option is to use the **[`find()`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find)** method which can accept the criteria and projection documents as parameters and append **[`limit(1)`](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries/limit)** to return just one document. For the projection object you would need to use the `select` key that holds an array of the projection fields:

```
var criteria = { _id: Library.mongo.objectId(libraryId) },
    projection = { select: [ "latitude", "longitude", "name", "address", "image" ] };

Library.find(criteria, projection).limit(1).exec(function (err, res) {
    var libObj = res[0];
    console.log(libObj );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@chridam Thanks a lot for your answer. I changed something and the script working well

```
var criteria = { _id: Library.mongo.objectId(libraryId) },
    projection = { latitude: 1, longitude: 1, name: 1, address: 1, image: 1 };

// Grab an instance of the mongo-driver
Library.native(function(err, collection) {        
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);

    // Execute any query that works with the mongo js driver
    collection.findOne(criteria, projection, function (err, libObj) {
        sails.log(libObj);
        sails.log(err);
    });
});
```